# Mongoid HABTM relationships across embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, embedded-documents

I'm trying to create a Mongoid N-N reference association between two embedded documents in Rails 4 however I'm finding it difficult to get my head round how this is done.

I started by adding the HABTM association to the relevant models below (`Track` and `Option`) but of course I'm getting the error saying this isn't allowed because they're both embedded.

```
class Brief
  embeds_many :tracks
end

class Track
  embedded_in :brief
  has_and_belongs_to_many :options
end
```

and

```
class Category
  embeds_many :options
end

class Option
  field :name, type: String
  field :track_ids, type: Array
  embedded_in :category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tracks

  def parent
    self.category
  end

  def tracks
    self.parent.tracks.where(:option_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

I completely understand why this is and know I need to reference the parent documents but here is where I run into trouble.

Ive been trying to add track ids to the `track_ids` via the console array but I end up getting the same error as before:

"Problem:
  Referencing a(n) Track document from the Option document via a relational association is not allowed since the Track is embedded.
Summary:
  In order to properly access a(n) Track from Option the reference would need to go through the root document of Track. In a simple case this would require Mongoid to store an extra foreign key for the root, in more complex cases where Track is multiple levels deep a key would need to be stored for each parent up the hierarchy."

I would be happy to store the extra foreign key but I have no idea how and in what format. If anybody can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because of the logic below.  If you are going to need to represent many-to-many relations, do not use a document model to store your state.  Use a relational one

===

You can't represent a many to many relation without an association/reference table/object.  If you don't have a reference table, then your update to either end could cause an infinite update as all your relations (and then their relations) will be touched (and possibly re-saved)

For example,

Track 1, => Option 1, 2, 3

Option 1, => Track 1, 2, 3

Track 2, => Option 1, 2

Option 2, => Track 1, 2

Track 3, => Option 1, 3, 4

Option 3, => Track 1, 3, 4

Now let's go ahead and edit Track 1,

1) update Track 1

2) Causes update in options 1, 2, 3

3) option 1 caused re=update of track 1, (infinite repeat of 1,2,3)

4) option 2 causes update of Tracks 1, 2 (infinite repeat again)

5) etc...

Comment: Yes ok that makes sense. Thanks for your answer. Back to the drawing board for this I think.